# How to store Firebase Database values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to store local variable's value into Global variable, but that just doesn't seem to work. Any help on this?

```
var xv = 0;
var yv = 0;

var itemx = firebase.database().ref().child("item").child("xval");
itemx.on('value', function(xvalue){
    xv = xvalue.val(); 
});

var itemy = firebase.database().ref().child("item").child("yval");
itemy.on('value', function(yvalue){
    yv = yvalue.val();
});

var start = graph.grid[aa][bb];
var end = graph.grid[xv][yv];
var result = astar.search(graph, start, end);
```

I'm unable to fetch the values of variables xv and yv outside the Firebase function.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot save an object to a variable defined as integer. Declare the variables without initializing them with any value like this and you are good to go.

```
var xv, yv;

var itemx = firebase.database().ref().child("item").child("xval");
itemx.on('value', function(xvalue){
    xv = xvalue.val(); // it contains an object to view it print on console.
    console.log(xvalue.val())
});

var itemy = firebase.database().ref().child("item").child("yval");
itemy.on('value', function(yvalue){
    yv = yvalue.val();
});
```